# How do you send a notification at a certain time that the user has entered in a text box in xcode 10?

Tags: swift, xcode, push-notification, notifications, alarm

I am trying to get a user to enter the time to take medicine or when they have an appointment in a text field and then send an alarm or notification at that time. I am a newbie so I don't know how to send notifications and such. I would need to do multiple of these depending on how many the user wants.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a place for getting an in-depth help with large problems. It's best for answering clearly defined questions. If you could narrow down your question to one thing that is preventing you from making progress and ask about that, it would be something we could help you with. See more details on how to post a question at this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Here is a link that might help you: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app

Answer (score 0):

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                content.title = "Title"
                content.body = "Body"
                content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

                let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
                let now = Date()
                var components = gregorian.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: now)

                // Change the time to 7:00:00 in your locale
                components.hour = 7
                components.minute = 0
                components.second = 0

                let date = gregorian.date(from: components)!

                let triggerDaily = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour,.minute,.second,], from: date)
                let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDaily, repeats: true)


                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: CommonViewController.Identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
                print("INSIDE NOTIFICATION")

                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: {(error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("SOMETHING WENT WRONG")
                    }
                })
```